# adjusting number of rows for each element in a list

Tags: r

I have a code that reads certain files and extracts specified data for further processing. The sample of a code is presented below:

```
library(readxl)
library(openxlsx)

revisedFiles<-choose.files()
dataList<-list()
length(dataList)<-3
## 'For' loop to select only relevant data

for( i in 1:length(revisedFiles)){
#Reading files
dummy<-read_excel(revisedFiles[i],sheet="DataSheet",range=cell_cols("F:I"))
dummy2<-read_excel(revisedFiles[i],sheet="DataSheet",range=cell_cols("D:D"))
#Attempt to check if number of rows are the same and work around it
if(nrow(dummy)<nrow(dummy2)){
diff<-abs(nrow(dummy)-nrow(dummy2))  
dummy[nrow(dummy)+diff,]<-c(rep("NA",length(diff)))
} else if(nrow(dummy)>nrow(dummy2)){
diff<-abs(nrow(dummy)-nrow(dummy2))  
dummy2[nrow(dummy2)+diff,]<-c(rep("NA",length(diff)))
}


# Separating data into 3 categories
nData<-cbind(dummy2,dummy[1])
sData<-cbind(dummy2,dummy[2])
bData<-cbind(dummy2,dummy[3])
#Adding each category to the separate level in the list
dataList[[1]]<-append(dataList[[1]],list(nData))
dataList[[2]]<-append(dataList[[2]],list(sData))
dataList[[3]]<-append(dataList[[3]],list(bData))
}
```

The problem is that I have the following error:

Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 231, 232

Previously, everyone suggested to make all elements the same length (by finding the largest element and make all elements of the same size).

Thanks to the Andre in the comments, I've added the 'if' function that seems to bypass the error. However, each level of a list has 7000+ lists when I only expect 26 (because I have 26 files that I read in the first place).

The example would be:

Suppose I have these 3 tables saved in 3 different s/s:

```
 Table 1                 Table 2                Table 3
 Name1  1   11  111      Name1   4   44  444    Name1  7   77  777  
 Name2  2   22  222      Name2   5   55  555    Name2  8   88  888
 Name3  3   33  333      Name3   6   66  666    Name3  9   99  999
```

I want to have a list that have 3 levels (1st level for 1 digit numbers,2nd level for 2 digit and 3rd level for 3 digit numbers). In each level, I want to keep values from each table separate. The output for this example would be,

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
1,2,3
[[1]][[2]]
4,5,6
[[1]][[3]]
7,8,9
```

Same for the other levels.
Thanks!

Comment: well the error seems to be in in the cbind section: => `cbind(mtcars, mtcars[-1,])`. You will need a `if` clause to catch and a rule to be applied if the number of rows differ.

Comment: So you were right. I've added the 'if' function that I'll edit in and then the 'for' loop worked. However, each level seems to have crazy amount of lists (7000+ when I only expect 26 from 26 files). Would you know why is this a case?

Comment: In order to get real and useful help, you will have to provide real data with example and desired outcome. Otherwise its impossible.

Comment: @AndreElrico I've added the example and adjusted the code

Comment: after `#Adding each category to the separate level in the list` try using `dataList[[i]] <- list(nData, sData, dData)` instead of your three lines of code.

Comment: It is not exactly what I need (as it saves the columns from the same table at each level)  but it is good enough (if not better then what I want) since the rest of the code can be easily modified. Thanks a lot!